# Reused cells in a UICollectionView show multiple UIImageViews when they should only show one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

Im having a problem with my `UICollectionView`. Initially it displays fine, showing a grid of cells, each cell with a single `UIImageView`. These `UIImageViews` are showing PNGs with transparency that are stored in the app's bundle.

My problem is, once the `UICollectionView` has been scrolled, some of the cells seem to be corrupt.

A corrupt cell shows multiple images stacked on top of each other, the top most image is the one it should be showing, and images underneath are the ones that should be used in other cells.

My best guess is that this has something to do with the way cells inside a `UICollectionView` are reused, but I am open to suggestions.

This is the delegate code I use for creating cells within the `UICollectionView`:

```
// creates the individual cells to go in the menu view
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // create collection view cell
    UICollectionViewCell * cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // create a uiview where we can place all views that need to go into this cell
    UIView * contents=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
    [contents setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contents];

    // add a button image
    NSString * buttonPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[[buttons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    UIImage * button=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:buttonPath];
    UIImageView * buttonView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:button];
    [buttonView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [buttonView setFrame:contents.bounds];
    [contents addSubview:buttonView];

    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];

    // add interactivity
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    // return the cell
    return cell;

}
```

I can provide more code if required.

How can I stop the cells from corrupting?

Comment: You are right, it is exactly the way you reuse the Cells. Because you are just adding layer after layer on your cell with the addSubview: calls.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding views to the `UICollectionViewCell` as they are being reused automagically by the `UICollectionView`. So the old `UIImageView`'s are still on the cell as you are adding one more as the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called.

DO NOT USE `addSubview:`!

Instead you could make a custom cell with all the views you want already in them. So that when the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called you only need to set the contents of this CustomCollectionViewCell instead.

This way it will certainly stop being corrupted.

---

How to build a CustomCell.

**Step1**: Create the .h & .m class.

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView; //this imageview is the only thing we need right now.

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize imageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])
    {
         //we create the UIImageView in this overwritten init so that we always have it at hand.
         imageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
         //set specs and special wants for the imageView here.
         [self addSubview:imageView]; //the only place we want to do this addSubview: is here!

         //You wanted the imageView to react to touches and gestures. We can do that here too.
         UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];


        //We can also prepare views with additional contents here!
        //just add more labels/views/whatever you want.
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)onButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    //the response to the gesture.
    //mind that this is done in the cell. If you don't want things to happen from this cell.
    //then you can still activate this the way you did in your question.

}
```

**Step2**: Import it!
Now that we created the CustomCell we can import it in the class we want to use it in.

**Step3**: Use it in action!

```
// creates the individual cells to go in the menu view
- (CustomCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // create collection view cell
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; //this is the place where the CustomCell does his magic.
    //Make sure to use the CustomCellReuseId that you register in the viewdidload/loadview (step4)

    // add a button image
    NSString * buttonPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[[buttons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:buttonPath]; //place the image on the CustemCell.imageView as we prepared.

    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row]; //we don't need this to access the cell but I left this in for your personal want.

/*
 * we can now do this from the CustomCell as well!
 *
    // add interactivity
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
*/
    // return the cell
    return cell;

}
```

**Step4**: Register the cell to the collectionView

in the viewDidLoad / loadView add this line:

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

**Step5**: Enjoy!
Your CustomCell is done. Now do whatever you like and don't forget to get some coffee too.

Comment: can you show how i would implement a CustomerCollectionViewCell ?

Comment: Of course. You want it done with foreknowledge of a storyboard or pure code?

Comment: I hate doing this in storyboard too :P Anyway this should be it in pure code. Let me know if everything is clear.

Comment: Thanks for doing this - Im playing about with it now - when you do `cell.imageView=...` you are setting the UIImageView in the custom cell class to a UIImage - if this makes any sense?

Comment: Ah yup it should be .imageview.image = theImage; good catch. There you set the image to the one you want yes. You can set a placeholder in the customcell if you want that. This can be really handy if u load the images in a background thread. This way u can just lazy load any image in any of the cells whenever you have a image done loading. (at least this is how i've done it with one of my apps). Also you're welcome ;) I love doing this and helping out.

Comment: ok, I am having "unrecognized selector" problems, specifically when I use the `imageView` property of the custom cell - I think its with this line `CustomCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusable...` - when I NSLog that it tells me its a `UICollectionViewCell` instead of a `CustomCell`

Comment: Ah you need to cast the cell still. ^^ just a sec updating now. Probably should make the return value (CustomCell *) too. I'm here until this is done correctly so Ima getting u that answer u need!

Comment: Many thanks Totumus! Unfortunately casting doesnt seem to have any effect - NSLogging that cell still tells me that its a `UICollectionViewCell` and not a `CustomCell`...

Comment: Ah i see what the problem is here:) You need to register the cell with the collectionview in the viewdidload (or load view). Use this:
 [_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"UseACustomCellIdentifierThatWillBeReusedLater"];

Comment: Perhaps you have a hint. My code is looking the same like yours and for me it does not work... http://stackoverflow.com/q/21334858/1933185

Comment: Should you use mageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];[self.contentView addSubview:imageView];

Comment: As long as you don't do it inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath: function. The CustomCell is fully customisable for your own design. This "custom"-cell and all that is inside is being properly reused by the system.

Comment: Totumus Maximus is there a way to reach you outside of stack overflow? I'm having trouble adding a UIView to custom cell without doing addSubview in the cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @AceGreen Yes there is, however this example will not only work for UIImageViews. It will also work for custom UIViews. Just replace the imageview with a random UIView of your making and try it :) You shouldn't need my help I think.

Comment: Yea I tried that. I already had it all setup but i can't seem to go without using the addSubview. My UIView in my CustomCell uses a custom class and somewhere its not being initialized by itself.

Comment: Well you can initialize it in the cellForItem i guess. Just make sure it is all prepared and added like above. There are cases where you dont want to prepare everything in the customcell because the cells changes based on the position in the table. This is not a problem at all. You just need a method inside the CustomCell that does everything you want changed. For example you prepare a cell with an uiview as above. Then want that view a different color for each row. In this case you want a method that changes the color inside the CellForItem. This should be everything you need?

Comment: My custom cell is not linked to the storyboard so my only option is to add the uiimageview and the uilabel as a subview. It's quite frustrating that the system re-adds the image on top of each other. Is there not another way around this?

Answer (score 6):

Right after

```
UICollectionViewCell * cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Just add this line,

```
[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: what is the reason for that? Besides, it did not work :(

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for a Swifty answer, add this function to your `CustomCell` class:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    contentView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    // replace contentView with the superview of the repeating content.
}
```

Comment: This worked for me great. For beginners it means you have to add the override function to swift file where you connected the outlets to. see 

`class DeviceCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Capability: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var brandLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SVGIconview: UIView!
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        SVGIconview.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
       
    }
}`

Comment: You saved my day ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

That Happen because you add every time a `UIImageView` to your cell for fix this problem you have to Make a custom cell and then use it like take:

**Custom.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

**Custom.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

**Your Controller**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString * buttonPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[[buttons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    UIImage * button=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:buttonPath];

    [cell.imageView setImage:button];

    return cell;
}
```

You have also to set 'CustomCell' like Identifier to the Cell in IB

Answer (score 1):

This is for removing duplicate text from label in uicollectionviewcell.

```
// Viewdidload
[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionviewcell class]     forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];



//in this method create label like this
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     for (UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews)
        {
            if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                [lbl removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
     UILabel *nameLbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 50, 20)];
     nameLbl.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];                                                                                                                                  
     nameLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLbl];
     return cell;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is adding UICollectionView programmatically and have a custom cell, in other words no XIB file, then you have to add this line to viewDidLoad

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (UIView *prevSubview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [prevSubview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This is how to remove them but they should not be generated so you don't need to delete them

Comment: this is useful when the previous collection view cell content has a subview and you want to remove that and add a new subview. this would be the case when you are setting it as an image view .

Comment: Describe what you post!