# UICollectionViewCell does not show images

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, reload, uicollectionviewcell

**How do I get the image shown in the cell, using UICollectionViewCell?**

Running the below stated code, I get the following output in the debugger. MagazineCell `initWithFrame` is called and when reloading the data the `setPhoto` is called. If I would put the setPhoto code in the initWithFrame method a reload would have no effect. 
**But the simulator does only show grey cells. No Image added, no backgroundcolor changed to yellow/red.** What do I miss?

```
[5230:70b] -[WebApi getSurroundImages] [Line 326] do surround composition
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell initWithFrame:] [Line 22] contentView frame: 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[SurroundViewController didComposition] [Line 146] reload Collection View Data
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
[5230:70b] -[MagazineCell setPhoto:] [Line 38] height: 104.000000, and width 104.000000
```

Do I change the following things

```
// in viewDidLoad
//    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MagazineCell class] 

// in - collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
[mCell.imageView setImageWithURL:photoURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"]];
//        [mCell setPhoto:photoURL];
```

I get the folloing output in the debbuger. The Images are shown, too small, and the MagazineCell is not called. Not that what I want

```
[5402:70b] -[WebApi getSurroundImages] [Line 326] do surround composition
[5402:70b] -[SurroundViewController didComposition] [Line 146] reload Collection View Data
```

Seems like the imageView is not working, wrong addressed, or something else. But I do not see my mistake... Below the complete code:

#### SurroundViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WebApi.h"
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@interface SurroundViewController : UICollectionViewController <WebApiDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sshare;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WebApi *swebapi;

@end
```

#### SurroundViewController.m

```c
#import "SurroundViewController.h"
#import "MagazineCell.h"
#import "LazyJoe.h"
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>

static NSString * const cellID = @"cellID";

@interface SurroundViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) LazyJoe *lazyJoe;

@end

@implementation SurroundViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sshare = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];   

    self.lazyJoe = [[LazyJoe alloc]init];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.lazyJoe; // Layout things are in the Flowlayout
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MagazineCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID]; 

    self.swebapi = [WebApi sharedInstance];
    self.swebapi.delegate = self;    
    [self.swebapi getSurroundImages]; // will call delegate didComposition    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.sshare.coData[indexPath.item]];
    //[mCell.imageView setImageWithURL:photoURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"]];
    [mCell setPhoto:photoURL];
    }
    return mCell;
}

-(void)didComposition {
    DLog(@"reload Collection View Data");
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
@end
```

#### MagazineCell.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>

@interface MagazineCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; 
// is connected to IB with the according CollectionView Cell in the Scene

-(void)setPhoto:(NSURL *)photoURL;

@end
```

#### MagazineCell.m

```c
#import "MagazineCell.h"

@implementation MagazineCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.frame;
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        DLog(@"contentView frame: %f", self.contentView.frame.size.height);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setPhoto:(NSURL *)photoURL {
    self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.frame;
    DLog(@"height: %f, and width %f", self.frame.size.height, self.contentView.frame.size.width);
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:photoURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"]];
}

@end
```

#### LazyJoe.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LazyJoe : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end
```

#### LazyJoe.m

```c
#import "LazyJoe.h"

@implementation LazyJoe

- (id)init {
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);    
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: After reading up on your issue, I have 2 things I'm not sure about. I'm not quite sure your UIImageView is being 'kept alive' by your app. Figure out what happens to your UIImageView-object and you probably find your answer. I also see that you used the AFNetworking framework (I love it tbh) but have you made sure ARC is properly set? If you want a quick prototype on how to place images on collectionCells make sure to try this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/! Let me know if this is useful for you :)

Comment: @TotumusMaximus AFNetworking works, as described in *Do I change the following things*-part. How do I debug *your UIImageView is being 'kept alive'*? Any Tips?

Comment: Set breakpoints or logs at the 'initwithframe' & 'setphoto' & 'cellforitem'. Check if it is null, reachable, and set with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (imgView != nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        UIButton * imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -60, 257, 200);
        [imageButton setImage: img forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        imageButton.tag = [selectorValue intValue];
        imageButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        [imageButton addTarget: self action: @selector(imageViewClicked: ) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview: imageButton];
    });
}
```