# Objective C > UITableViewCell button not depressing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have the following button being created in the cellForRowAtIndexPath section for this tableView:

```
UIButton *sched_button_a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
sched_button_a1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 52);
CGRect frame_a1 = sched_button_a1.frame;

// Resize height based on length of appointment
frame_a1.size.height = heightCalc;
sched_button_a1.frame = frame_a1;

[sched_button_a1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sched_button_a1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"APPT: %@", APPT_ID ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
sched_button_a1.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[sched_a1 addSubview:sched_button_a1];
```

As you can see it's calling showAppointment which is presently just:

```
-(void)showAppointment:(UIButton*)sender {

    NSLog(@"Button pushed");

}
```

showAppointment is also defined here:

```
-(void)showAppointment:(UIButton*)sender;
```

The button shows up fine and gets the correct text and background and appears to be in the foreground, however, when I click on it nothing happens and it doesn't look like the button even gets depressed.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Edit: I have gone back and removed the sched_a1 view so that the button is directly created in the contentView and this had no effect.  It still appears that the only gesture being recognized is the one used to scroll the table.  Tapping the button does not appear to change the color of the text or otherwise indicate that the button has been pressed and no log entry is created.

Edit 2: Added cellForRowAtIndexPath to paste bin
http://pastebin.com/WXezfW96

Comment: Can you give your entire cellforrowatindexpath method?

Comment: Yes, what ^^ said, he could be a cell reuse issue. Also, you can set the background color of the button normally, without having to use the layer.. Is there a reason why you're doing it that way?

Comment: No, it's just the way I learned. This is my first app.  I'll update the question with my entire cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @BrooksHanes the pertinent code has been added. There are other if() inside the section normally but they aren't relevant and pasting them would have been the code exceptionally long.

Comment: Scott, with all due respect that is the most horrifying implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath I've ever seen... ALL of that code is called for every single cell every time the tableView scrolls... Having a while-loop, sq-lite stuff, etc., is absolutely not the way to go about what you want to do. You should pre-fetch all of that stuff and have it in a data-source array, and then you can access all of the contents for each cell directly, without having to do all of that logic. I've had some very complex table view's in my day, and cellForRowAtIndexPath should be only a few lines of code...

Comment: That may or may not be related to your problem with the button, but I definitely think it is worth addressing because you'll have massive performance issues for larger table views implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath like that.

Comment: @Mike, no worries, this is my first ever app and I'm literally teaching myself objective-c as I go.  Do you have an example or perhaps a link to a tutorial for something like that?

Comment: Re Mikes comment above on your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath, you might find this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269266/reused-cells-in-a-uicollectionview-show-multiple-uiimageviews-when-they-should-o/19269445#19269445

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, which I struggled to understand. The solution I came up with was to set the bounds of the button as well and also check for UIControlEventTouchDown rather than UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Comment: Ok, what is "sched_a1"? Could you show where that is defined?

Comment: sched_a1 is the UIView that the button and 2 labels are in: UIView *sched_a1       = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:111];

Comment: I tried adding a tap gesture to it as well and it still acts like it's not getting touched. Almost seems like it's being detected on the row (so it can move up/down) and not on the button.  Maybe that's it? But if so - how to fix?

Comment: If I put the button anywhere outside the tableview instead it works fine.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help. I've tried your code in one of my tableviews and it works, i.e. the button fires correctly. It could be an issue with using addSubView inside of cellForRowAtIndex each time (as opposed to adding it conditionally only when the cell is first instantiated), as I know when you do this, and scroll the table view, it can cause problems with the buttons firing.

Comment: When I tried your code, it doesn't fire only after I have scrolled the table view (i.e. when it gets confused due to the cell re-use/addSubview issue mentioned earlier). Is this what you get - i.e. does ShowAppointment get called if you just run your app and tap the first row on the screen without scrolling the table view?

Comment: I usually just immediately push it, however, I've been needing to scroll to a past date first as thats where the last time I entered an appointment was.  I'll make one for today and then try it again.

Comment: No change but I'll work on using the custom cell as you mentioned and see what comes of it.  Thanks everyone for the comments and help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `cancelsTouchesInView`? If you added tap gesture, I think the tap gesture or the tap in table cell overrides the touches in your button. Try using this code:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tap= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    tap.delegate = self;
    [yourButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

But don't forget to add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in your .h file

But I agree on Mike. Make it short and simple when creating table cell. I think you can use custom cell subclass and xib file.

I'm also new to objective C so if I say something wrong I'm sorry, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you pasted above and it doesn't make any effect.  I think for the time being I'll have to have them arrive at appointment details via a different method. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *sched_button_a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

in this change `UIButtonTypeCustom` to `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`

Answer (score 0):

Scott, you may want to try my famous troubleshooting technique:

1. Determine whether the **button** or the **action** is the root cause:

> ```
>     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
>     [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected]
> ```

---

2. Instead of:

> ```
> -(void)showAppointment:(UIButton*)sender {
> ```

try

> ```
> -(void)showAppointment:(id*)sender {
> ```

---

3. Use breakpoints.
4. If none of the above works consider refactoring your code that looks a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have checked the code you wrote, it is working fine. Can you check if you have written similar to the code below in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *Identifier = @"Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];

    if(cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];

    }

        UIButton *sched_button_a1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        sched_button_a1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 52);

        CGRect frame_a1 = sched_button_a1.frame;


        [sched_button_a1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [sched_button_a1 setTitle:@"Your Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        sched_button_a1.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:sched_button_a1];


    return cell;

}
```

I was not able to debug further as you have not kept your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath code. Hope this could help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a button type of UIButtonTypeCustom, you will need to set the attributes for UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateSelected so that you achieve the effect you want for appearing to press the button.
You can change the title color or the background image for the highlighted and selected states using one of the following UIButton methods:

```
- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

As an additional note regarding the code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you shouldn't be getting the data from sql in the method it would be destructive to your table view performance, get all the data you need before and have them stored in object in an array and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method you would just update the values labels from the object for the row.