# Loading more data to collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to load more data to collection view . What happens is that it cells with images that i already had, are appears again in the next new cells,some other cells are disappear, and it becomes a real mess.

I have checked all of my data source, to see there are no duplicates, and all images are unique. Somehow after he loads the new cells, i scroll and i see previous images, and as i do that more and more(loading new images to the collection) i get more duplicates,and missing cells.

Seems that he totally messing my cells .

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for (long i = numPreviousCells; i < [[DataSourceManager SharedDataSourceManager].mainData count]; i++)
    [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];


[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];
```

Here i log `i` and i get indexes from `17 - 34` for example . (so i had 17 images,now i have 34 , and so the new indexes are **from 17 to 34** )

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: The problem lies in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  Cells are reused when they move off screen.  So you must ensure that you reset all the content before setting the new details.  See for example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269266/reused-cells-in-a-uicollectionview-show-multiple-uiimageviews-when-they-should-o).

Comment: @pbasdf I actually have a serious mechanism to take care of the reusable cells, and i dont see any duplicates while scrolling, but only after i reload the new data, so if when you add new cells to a collection, he just ignored them and load the old reusable cells, whats the point of insertCells ?

Comment: try to ignore the fact that i have 105 points here, i am 3 years with this..i know what are reusable cells..

Comment: Please also attach screenshot for more clarification.

Comment: I cant put a screen shot, its in stealth mode. Also , how a screen shot will show you duplicates? i need 5 screen shots of 30 images so you can see duplicates..

Comment: please remove all get data from array which you have use in collection view when the for loop started. Means First you have remove data from array then after use for loop & after complete you for loop reload collection view.

Comment: what??? your sentence is really not so clear...

Comment: Apologies if I jumped the gun regarding reusable cells.  How do you update numPreviousCells?  How and when does the above code get executed?