# Cell is being overzealously reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UICollectionViewController and some cells (UICollectionViewCell). I want to draw images on some of the cells. This works fine, but when I scroll, some of the cells seems to be being unnecessarily reused, in other words cells which I didn't explicitly drawn on are being drawn on (only after scrolling).

In my cell I do the following:

```
imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width/4)-1, (self.bounds.size.height/4)-1, 30, 30));
imageView!.image = imageTick
self.addSubview(self.lblDay)
self.addSubview(imageView!)
```

I create an image view and set its image then add the label and image view.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Just of the case of completeness here is how I initialise the images for the cell:

```
let imageTick:UIImage = UIImage(named: "star")!
var imageView:UIImageView? = nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCell`s are reused by the system, so you need to handle the possibility of a cell being reused in the `prepareForReuse` method in `UICollectionViewCell`, by clearing everything from the cell (setting the image to nil etc.)

[Here is the doc for UICollectionReusableView that declares that](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse)

[Here is the doc for UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:) You can see in that doc, for the method `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` it talks about calling `prepareForReuse` if there is an available cell to reuse.

Comment: Very nice tip. I nil the image, and it does not arbitrarily appear somewhere it is not needed. But now I need to rerender the image. I set a boolean in the cell when it was selected, but I should probably reset that also in prepareForReuse. Irregardless I am not sure when I can redraw the image.

Comment: @dasPing you can set the correct image for your cell in your dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier implementation

Comment: @dasPing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269266/reused-cells-in-a-uicollectionview-show-multiple-uiimageviews-when-they-should-o take a look at that too, it suggests not using addsubview for your imageview